# Can I get subprocess(...) to return after launching?

Tags: python, websocket

I have a python script that launches an app using `subprocess`, but in order to communicate with it, I also use websockets (there's a plugin on the app that expects a server to communicate with). The code looks like:

```
#!python3
import os
import subprocess

import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print("< {}".format(name))

    greeting = "Hello {}!".format(name)
    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print("> {}".format(greeting))

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

subprocess.call(['foo.exe', 'd:\\data\\foo_data.txt'])
```

The problem I have is that the process won't ever launch because the server's been started. Is it possible to use `subprocess` to launch an app and then return control to the parent process? Conversely is it possible to launch the server (and receiving messages) without looping forever?

Comment: That's `subprocess.Popen()`.  The other functions in that module wait for the process to finish.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Can you submit it as an answer and I'll flag it as such.